# Zoom into cell on selection with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a grid of images that are handled by a UICollectionView. What I would like to do is transition to another View Controller on selection of a cell by zooming into the image and have that image take up a large portion of the screen in the child View Controller. Is there any good way of creating this behavior.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate a UICollectionView cell on selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694192/animate-a-uicollectionview-cell-on-selection)

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing. It's stupidly complicated, it seems. Any progress?

Answer (score 1):

In Child view controller You can add a scroll view and can add property like that.

```
   scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
   scrollView.delegate = self;
   scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Add an image view :-

```
   imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imgnamed:@"image01.png"]];
   imageView.userIntractionEnabled = YES;
   imageView.autoSizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

   [scrollview addSubView:imageView];
```

Calculate minimum scale zoom level :-

```
   float minimumScale = [scrollView frame].size.width / [imageView frame].size.width;
   scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0   // you can exeed as per your requirment
   scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale;
   scrollView.zoomScale = minimumScale;
```

Hope this help you. If Any question or problem then ask in comments.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would use a custom segue. In the UICollectionView documentation, Apple recommends using a fake cell when moving it across your CollectionView. 
You can do this with storyboard or programatically. 
Inside your -prepareForSegue: method, place the image from the selected cell on the screen centered over the cell, then animate the scaling in the segue.

Custom Segue guide: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html

Ray's site is also boss:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2